# How to properly update value of an index in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the code below which updates the values of a specific index in an array which works well.

```
var pushTest = false

if(this.forUpdate.length == 0){
   this.forUpdate.push(value);
}else{
   for(var i=0;i<this.forUpdate.length;i++){
   //check if the value id is existing in the array
       if(value.item.id == this.forUpdate[i].item.id){
           this.forUpdate.splice(this.forUpdate.indexOf(i), 1);
           this.forUpdate.push(value);
           pushTest = true
        }
    }
    if(pushTest == false && this.forUpdate.length > 0){
       this.forUpdate.push(value);
    }
}
```

**Results:**

First update

[image]

Second update (same id with first update)

[image]

Third update (different id)

[image]

This is all good, except, if I update again with the id 1, my array is updated but my items that has an id of 61 is gone. The content of my array is all the items with Id 1. What I want is just to update the item with an id of 1, after updating, the content of an array should the items with an id 1 (with the updated values) and id 61. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let pushTest = false;
forUpdates.forEach((a, i) => {
  if (a.item.id === value.item.id) {
    forUpdates[i] = a;
    pushTest = true;
  }
});
if (!pushTest) forUpdates.push(value);
```

Your problem is that your are splicing the array while iterating it. The i variable remains the same while your next Item is now you newly pushed one.
I suggest avoiding mutations of arrays (My method does not avoid it either).
To avoid mutations you need to declare a new Array each time you are updating it, and copy the needed values.